# Access dataframe with multi-level index on pandas v1.0.3

Tags: pandas, multi-index, python-3.8

I'm trying to access a row of the dataframe dtSortedTable by

```
dtSortedTable.loc[decisionCountSorted.index[0]]
```

dtSortedTable is

```
         X0  X1  X2
(D1, G2)  A   B   C
(D2, G1)  A  A  A
(D2, G0)  A  A   C
```

decisionCountSorted indexes look like:

```
Index([('D1', 'G2'), ('D2', 'G1'), ('D2', 'G0')], dtype='object')
```

The indexes of decisionCountSorted are exactly the same as dtSortedTable. The indexes are multilevel with 2 levels. Why am I getting the below error? I need to run some tests on decisionCountSorted and extract the corresponding rows from dtSortedTable. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/logicsim/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'D1'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tkazi/Documents/Code/logicsim/logic.py", line 183, in <module>
    dtFixed = dtConsensus(dtSortedTable,quorumCount)
  File "/Users/tkazi/Documents/Code/logicsim/logic.py", line 119, in dtConsensus
    print(dtSortedTable.loc[decisionCountSorted.index[0]])
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/logicsim/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1762, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/logicsim/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1272, in _getitem_tuple
    return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/logicsim/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1389, in _getitem_lowerdim
    section = self._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/logicsim/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1965, in _getitem_axis
    return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/logicsim/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 625, in _get_label
    return self.obj._xs(label, axis=axis)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/logicsim/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3537, in xs
    loc = self.index.get_loc(key)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/logicsim/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'D1'
```

Comment: You don't have a MultiIndex. You have a plain Index with tuples as the labels. You can fix this with `df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.index)`, and then you can use all of the nice MultiIndex slicing, like `df.xs('D1', level=0)`

Comment: Thanks - one of the functions along the way changed the multi-index to a normal one! Much appreciated :)